# Очистить данные в function(data) после отправки запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, сервер, запрос

Подскажите возможно ли после отправки AJAX запроса очистить данные в `function(data)`?

```
setInterval(function() {   $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/1.php",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  // Выводим координаты из 1.php
                  success: function(data){
        ....

    },
              error: function(){
                  alert('Проблема с загрузкой скрипта');
                  }
                    }); 
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Простите, но зачем? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data = undefined
или
delete data

Но. В success данные попадают после ответа сервера, т.е. data не существует, пока не получен ответ сервера